# Neo4j - Browser Visualization Error

Tags: java, neo4j

I am trying to use the 'Hello World' for Neo4j. The problem is that I when I boot up the server and check the neo4j's browser (localhost:7474), I cannot see any graphic visualisation of my nodes.

```
import java.io.File;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class MyFirstMain
{
    private static final String DB_PATH = "/neo4j/data/graph.db";

    public String greeting;

    // START SNIPPET: vars
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
    Node firstNode;
    Node secondNode;
    Relationship relationship;
    // END SNIPPET: vars

    // START SNIPPET: createReltype
    private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType
    {
        KNOWS
    }
    // END SNIPPET: createReltype

    public static void main( final String[] args )
    {
        MyFirstMain hello = new MyFirstMain();
        hello.createDb();
//        hello.removeData();
//        hello.shutDown();
    }

    void createDb()
    {
         // START SNIPPET: startDb
        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );
        registerShutdownHook( graphDb );
        // END SNIPPET: startDb

        // START SNIPPET: transaction
        try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
        {
            // Database operations go here
            // END SNIPPET: transaction
            // START SNIPPET: addData
            firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
            firstNode.setProperty( "message", "Hello, " );
            secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
            secondNode.setProperty( "message", "World!" );

            relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode, RelTypes.KNOWS );
            relationship.setProperty( "message", "brave Neo4j " );
            // END SNIPPET: addData

            // START SNIPPET: readData
            System.out.print( firstNode.getProperty( "message" ) );
            System.out.print( relationship.getProperty( "message" ) );
            System.out.print( secondNode.getProperty( "message" ) );
            // END SNIPPET: readData

            greeting = ( (String) firstNode.getProperty( "message" ) )
                    + ( (String) relationship.getProperty( "message" ) )
                    + ( (String) secondNode.getProperty( "message" ) );

            // START SNIPPET: transaction
            tx.success();
        }
        // END SNIPPET: transaction
    }

     // START SNIPPET: shutdownHook
    private static void registerShutdownHook( final GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
    {
        // Registers a shutdown hook for the Neo4j instance so that it
        // shuts down nicely when the VM exits (even if you "Ctrl-C" the
        // running application).
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        } );
    }
    // END SNIPPET: shutdownHook
}
```

I do NOT want to use anything else, except the neo4j's built in browser.
How should I proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You **must shut down the server**, then create your data, then start the server again, you cannot use the same data directory from two database processes at the same time.

Your DB_PATH is also wrong, you can't have a star in there.

Comment: Leaving aside the db_path (where I put the star just as a generic name here in SO), I did what you proposed. It seems that db is working, but still, there is no visual representation of my nodes. :S

Comment: And you have to run a query to see your nodes. But only if you do the above.

Comment: I did the above and tried to use the MATCH n RETURN n LIMIT 25 that neo4j provides by default for all nodes. I got 0 in return, even though the nodes are correctly set up.

Comment: I removed everything and reinstalled neo4j through homebrew (which I was using before as well) and now it's working! Thank you for your help.